# 'No match for operator=' error in basic code

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm very new to coding (like one day ago), so you can pretty much assume I know nothing. I'm finding it very hard to debug my extremely simple programs and most of the help I've seen online is either over my head or too specific to the program.

This is the code I'm working on now.

```
/*
 * LogBase8.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 13, 2015
 *      Author: Holly
 */
//This program calculates the log base 8 of a number.

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Declare variables and constants.
float x, log_8_x;

int main()
{

//Prompt user to input number.
cout << "This program will calculate the log base 8 of a number. Input number to calculate" << endl;
cin >> x;

//Calculate log_8_x.
log_8_x = log(x) / log(8);

//Print log_8_x.
cout << "The log base 8 of " << x << " is " << log_8_x << endl;

//End main.
return (0);

}
```

I have an error in the `log_8_x = log(x) / log(8);` line that says

```
no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' and 'double')
```

I'm using Eclipse, if that's relevant.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/Kwe7mg) if I fix the broken formatting, and gives completely different errors if I don't. Are you sure this is the code you're compiling? Or does your real code say something like `cin = x;`? Or declare `log_8_x` as something other than `float`?

Comment: If you're just starting, I suggest you follow a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for learninig.

Comment: Mike Seymour, I just copy and pasted it right out of Eclipse.

Comment: Angew, I'm in a college course right now, just definitely still in the early stages. Not sure how much our textbook is helping me

Comment: Any chance you have line wrapping turned on in your editor and there's no real line break in your code?

Comment: Well the wrapping is only here on the forum because the line is too long to fit. It's just one line in my program

Comment: @HollyEvans There is no line wrapping in code blocks here. If it's just one line in your program, *please edit the question to reflect that.* You're confusing everybody.

Comment: I'm sorry. I am also confused. Didn't know I did that

Comment: This is not your real code!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Then what is my real code? This is exactly what I typed in. I just copy and pasted it

Comment: After the edit, [your code works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0791ee98e47d7807). So the problem must be in something you haven't shown.

Comment: Any chance you have `log` defined as a macro somewhere? Try looking at the preprocessed output (`gcc -E`) and see what the code in `main` looks like after macro substitution.

Comment: BTW, use of Eclipse is not relevant. If anything, your compiler might be.

Comment: Okay, I edited the question and added the only other things on the whole page.

Comment: I just installed everything like 3 hours ago, and nothing has ran yet. I've built something without error messages, but it wouldn't run. I assumed I was coding wrong, but I'm seeing now that I probably messed up the installation. I installed Visual Studios originally but I was getting all kinds of errors about not being able to access the libraries and I couldn't fix them, so I installed MinGW instead, but I'm sure something got mixed up along the way.

Comment: @HollyEvans: Nope, because you are not invoking `=` on an istream anywhere in this code! The error suggests that in your real code `log_8_x` is an `istream`. Do you have `std::cin = log(x) / log(8);` in some other source file, by accident?

Comment: I don't have any other source files? I made a new C++ project and then created one source file. I typed what is above and then got the error message when I tried to compile it.

Comment: Can you try simplifying it further? Such as replacing the offending line with just `log_8_x = x / 8.0;` and similar, trying it after each step, until the error disappears? Then post when this happened, it might help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @HollyEvans: I can't really help you any further. I've told you what the situation is and can't do anything about it from here! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have other errors as stated in your question, but anyway putting a `\` to escape the newline appearing in the string literal here

```
cout << "This program will calculate the log base 8 of a number. Input \
```

fixes your compilation errors.

See [fully working sample here](http://ideone.com/9k24Lt) please.

Comment: The \ worked to get rid of the original error but now it's telling me I have an unknown escape sequence and won't compile because of that?

Comment: You probably have something after the \

Comment: @HollyEvans Either put the string literal into a single line, or ensure the backslash is the very last character in the continued line.

Comment: Okay, the \ is the very last character, but it's telling me it's unknown

Comment: @HollyEvans Are you 100% positive there is no trailing whitespace after the \ ?

Comment: @Angew Yes, tapping the right arrow through takes me right to the next line, no spaces